# Missing Pokemon Go coins?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I have a problem with Pokecoins. The last three days I was playing and my bag was full. I slept, then in the morning I found that my Pokecoins were less by almost 4000 coins! I opened my bag I found that the capacity is 600 and got 3 Lucky Eggs, 200 Balls and 3 Incense. I contacted support and they haven't replied yet.

Did anyone experience this issue? Are they going to return my coins back if there is a bug?

Comment: Sounds like your brother/sister/cousin/parent/dog/cat/hamster bought you a bunch of stuff.

Comment: If you had less coins but more things that can be bought with coins there is a pretty obvious assumption that can be made. As DanmakuGrazer says chances are somebody you know used your phone/account and spent the coins. Failing that it is possible somebody hacked your account and did it but I can't see any reason why they would have done so. You could try checking the journal in game to see if there is any obvious usage that wasn't yours (eg pokemon being caught when you were asleep) which could confirm usage of your account. Sadly I doubt support will refund the purchases though.

Comment: I check my google account history and no one logged into it. Based on journal no usage  except mine, because of that I assume that there is a bug with their laggy application. The sad part almost all items I don't need them hope they return them back I will try my best to see support and if they didn't refund I believe its good way to lose customers

Answer (score 0):

If you attempted to purchase things but got an error, that may be the same issue I ran into. I tried to purchase a single Incubator, but it gave an error and said to try again later. Following instructions, I tried again later. Same error. I tried again, and at least one more time. About an hour later, I looked at my profile screen and saw I had 0 coins instead of the 600 I was supposed to have. It had actually processed each purchase despite telling me to try again.

The support for the game seems to be nonexistent at the moment. I also have received no response to my complained about a glitch taking 3 eggs without giving pokemon and with 3 paid-for incubator uses deducted.